# Download CSV file in Java Servlet

Tags: java, csv, servlets

```
String fileName = "/CSVLogs/test";
         String fileType = "csv";
         resp.setContentType(fileType);

         resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=test.csv");

         File my_file = new File(fileName);

         OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
         int length;
         while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }
         in.close();
         out.flush();
```

I need to download a csv file but it seems to return **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER"**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/TestServlet/ConfigServlet?do=downloadLogs" method="post" style="height:68px;">
```

> UPDATE

```
resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            try
            {
                OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                InputStream in = StorageUtil.getInstance().getFile("/CSVLogs/test.csv").getInputStream();
            /*    InputStream in = StorageUtil.getInstance().getCSVLogsZip().getInputStream();*/
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                 int length;
                 while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    in.close();
                    outputStream.flush();
                 }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
```

I still get the same error. 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER**

(drunk) Why am I getting this error >_<

Comment: will you discuss the whole exception info?  I mean in which line exception has occur..

Comment: it occurs in getOutputStream()

Comment: post the full stack trace

Comment: You are calling response.getOutputStream();
 in JSP which is illegal. You should use either ServletResponse.getOutputStream() or ServletResponse.getWriter().

Comment: that is in Java. :O @KuldeePChoudharY

Comment: if you want to check whether it is running or not then you can take a JSP instead of servlet and try this code... :P

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY i don't get it (drunk) i need help huhuhuh

Comment: go into my profile, check my email id and send me your problem.... otherwise i have to go to get drunk :P :P.. Cheer's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.setContentType("application/x-rar-compressed");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.csv\"");
```

For writing the file in OutputStream, try following

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("your_csv_file.csv");
byte[] b = new byte[fis.available()];
outputStream.write(b);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Use BufferedOutputStream instead of OutputStream like:
BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());

Comment: Why are you closing the input stream inside your while loop ..move that part outsinde and write it in the end. Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes. thank you! but I got a question. it shows "null" when I open the csv file using notepad++

Comment: what I discovered is that the length declared of the new byte..
ex byte[] outputByte = new byte[1024];
will be the length of the csv file.. (drunk)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.csv\"");
try
{
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int length;
     while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
 in.close();
     outputStream.flush();
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    model.closeConnection();
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: used this code but I still get the same error. WHyyyyyy :( (check my edit)

Comment: resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); 

Why this?

Answer (score 1):

java/servlet code you supplied works perfectly fine. 
i call the servlet CSVD as below:

```
< form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="CSVD" method="post" style="height:68px;">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
< /form>
```

or through anchor this way    < a href="/CSVDownloadApp/CSVD">click here to download csv< /a>

possibly your error is coming for a different reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response){ 
    String sourceFile = "c:\\source.csv";
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        String disposition = "attachment; fileName=outputfile.csv";
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition);
        response.setHeader("content-Length", String.valueOf(stream(inputStream, response.getOutputStream())));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error occurred while downloading file {}",e);
    }
}
```

And the stream method should be like this.

```
private long stream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {

try (ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(input); WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output)) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10240);
    long size = 0;

    while (inputChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
        buffer.flip();
        size += outputChannel.write(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    }
    return size;
}
```

}

Comment: If CSV file is created and stored in the server, then above method will work... Nice Answer :)